# I can't pass value to the other form class

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Basic 2005... I've been trying to pass value to other form class but it's not working.

Here's my code in frmLogin form:

```
    Imports System.Data.Odbc

Public Class frmLogIn
Dim Myconn As New OdbcConnection("Dsn=MS Access Database;dbq=D:\GRADING\dbTrip.mdb;defaultdir=D:\GRADING;driverid=25;fil=MS Access;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;uid=admin")
    Dim MyForm As New frmLimited
    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        Dim MyDSUser As New DataSet
        Dim MyDAUser As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblAccount WHERE Username = '" & Me.txtUser.Text & "'", Myconn)

        If MyDAUser.Fill(MyDSUser, "tblAccount") = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("No Account Found", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

        Else
            If MyDSUser.Tables("tblAccount").Rows(0)("password").ToString = Me.txtPass.Text Then
                Me.btnLogin.Enabled = True
                Dim varID As Integer = MyDSUser.Tables("tblAccount").Rows(0)("ID")
                Dim MyDSRoles As New DataSet
                Dim MyDARoles As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblRoles WHERE ID = " & varID & " ", Myconn)

                MyDARoles.Fill(MyDSRoles, "tblRoles")
                If MyDSRoles.Tables("tblRoles").Rows(0)("Role").ToString = "Administrator" Then
                    Me.Hide()
                    frmAdmin.Show()
                Else
                    MyForm.MyVar = varID
                    frmLimited.Show()

                End If

            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Password Mismatch", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

            End If

        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

And here's my code in frmLimited form:

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc

Public Class frmLimited
Dim Myconn As New OdbcConnection("Dsn=MS Access Database;dbq=D:\GRADING\dbTrip.mdb;defaultdir=D:\GRADING;driverid=25;fil=MS Access;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;uid=admin")
    Public MyVar As Integer
Private Sub frmLimited_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.lblName.Text = MyVar

    End Sub
End Class
```

The value of varID in frmLogin is what I am trying to pass to the other form called frmLimited in MyVar that has been declared as Public. I don't think that the Imports System.Data.Odbc affects the entire code. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Declare sub new() in frmLimited and pass the id to it... For example `Sub New(ByVal intID as integer)` then inside this method set your variable. Also move the declaraction of MyForm to under your varID declaration. The pass the id `Dim MyForm As New frmLimited(varID)`

Comment: Also instead of frmLimited.Show use the instance you created. For example: My Form.Show. frmLimited is the class but you already instantiated this class with MyForm, so use it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using Visual Studio 2005?

Comment: Sir if you don't mind... Can you please revise my code? Thanks.

Comment: Got it Sir... Thank you for the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very simple here, it's all about these three lines:

```
Dim MyForm As New frmLimited

MyForm.MyVar = varID
frmLimited.Show()
```

Your code creates an instance of `frmLimited`, changes the value of the variable `MyVar` which belongs to the instance that was created (MyForm), and then you try to `show` the original form `frmLimited`, not the instance that you created `MyForm`

So, you just need to change the following line:

```
frmLimited.Show()
```

With this one

```
MyForm.Show()
```

And the problem is solved :)

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You could make a property for the variable on frmLimited and pass it from MyForm:

frmLimited

```
Public Class frmLimited
Private _myVar as Integer
Public Property MyVar as Integer
' Get & Set
End Property

Dim Myconn As New OdbcConnection("Dsn=MS Access Database;dbq=D:\GRADING\dbTrip.mdb;defaultdir=D:\GRADING;driverid=25;fil=MS Access;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;uid=admin")
Private Sub frmLimited_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.lblName.Text = _myVar

    End Sub
End Class
```

MyForm

```
 If MyDSRoles.Tables("tblRoles").Rows(0)("Role").ToString = "Administrator" Then
                    Me.Hide()
                    frmAdmin.Show()
                Else
                    frmLimited.MyVar = varID '<--
                    frmLimited.Show()

                End If
```